# Console Application or WebService

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a functionality that will generate around 2000 excel sheets. THe process will accept input from front end web application. I dont want my web application to wait till the process of generating the excel files is over. I should write a console application and trigger it through web application or a web service? Whic is the better way of implementation?
Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: Why not do it asynchronously - kick it off on a background thread.

Comment: I am not very comfortable with Threads. If user closes the browser after triggering the process, will it still continue in thread?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it might not.  In that case you might want to look at a web service, but I'd be cautious of creating a web service that is significantly lengthy in running.  You might be better of looking at other ways to do this - perhaps put the data in a database and have a job or SSIS package kick off the work based on the data.  Just another idea to consider.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This also sounds to be a better option. Need to explore on this.

Comment: @Tim - terrible idea, web apps are designed to be stateless and not have background processing

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - I agree.  As I said (though not very clearly), it wasn't something that I would consider as the first or best option, hence my other suggestion.

Comment: SSIS is not suitable option. I need to generate multiple files based on few conditions and loops. I believe SSIS will take longer time in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing excel-gen as a task in a database, then have a background service constantly running, checking that task queue, processing it (creating spreadsheets), then finally updating job records as done. Your asp.net app can in turn, aside from creating job records, simply check on status periodically or on page-refresh.

Comment: The process of generating excel is carried out only once every quarter. This is a manual process right now. Running a service constantly will make that server slow as there are other application also residing on that server

Comment: Then manually run the tool that generates those files every 3 months - I don't know what to tell you. The closest you'll get to automating that double-click is maybe scheduling it (e.g. using task scheduler). No long-running task is a perfect fit for an asp.net app, especially when the app's pool is left at its default settings, related to app-recycling/reset. BTW, service that does minimal work 100% of the time won't even be noticed on a decent server, as far as the CPU time it's consuming is concerned (also, is that your only server?).